# Same service base class for generic entities

Tags: c#, generics

I've implemented some converter classes that convert specific types to byte arrays and vice versa. 
This converters are injected into entities that contains additional information.

I've also implemented some specific entity services that do stuff based on the information stored in the entity classes.

Problem is that I need x different services to handle all possible entity objects. Is there a ways to instantiate the service without specifying the converter type?

Converter classes:

```
abstract class Converter<TValue>
{
    public abstract byte[] ConvertFromValue(TValue value);
    public abstract TValue ConvertToValue(byte[] value);
}

class DoubleConverter : Converter<double>
{
    public double Coefficient { get; private set; }
    public DoubleConverter(double coefficient) { Coefficient = coefficient; }
    public override byte[] ConvertFromValue(double value) { return BitConverter.GetBytes(value * Coefficient); }
    public override double ConvertToValue(byte[] value) { return BitConverter.ToDouble(value, 0) / Coefficient; }
}

class StringConverter : Converter<string>
{
    public Encoding Encoding { get; private set; }
    public StringConverter(Encoding encoding) { Encoding = encoding; }
    public override byte[] ConvertFromValue(string value) { return Encoding.GetBytes(value); }
    public override string ConvertToValue(byte[] value) { return Encoding.GetString(value); }
}
```

Entities using the converter:

```
abstract class Base<TValue>
{
    protected Converter<TValue> Converter;
    public Base(Converter<TValue> converter) { Converter = converter; }
    public byte[] Convert(TValue value) { return Converter.ConvertFromValue(value); }
}

class Foo<TValue> : Base<TValue>
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public Foo(string id, Converter<TValue> converter) : base(converter) { Id = id; }
}

class Bar<TValue> : Base<TValue>
{
    public Bar(Converter<TValue> converter) : base(converter) { }
}
```

Entity services that do stuff:

```
abstract class Service<TValue, TBase>
    where TBase : Base<TValue>
{
    public abstract void Do(TBase entity, TValue value);
}

class FooService<TValue> : Service<TValue, Foo<TValue>>
{
    public override void Do(Foo<TValue> entity, TValue value) {/* Foo specific stuff */}
}

class BarService<TValue> : Service<TValue, Bar<TValue>>
{
    public override void Do(Bar<TValue> entity, TValue value) {/* Bar specific stuff */}
}
```

Problem is that I have to create the FooService n-times depending on how many different type converters are used.

```
var twice = new DoubleConverter(2);
var half = new DoubleConverter(0.5);
var str = new StringConverter(Encoding.ASCII);

var foo1 = new Foo<double>("Twice Foo", twice);
var foo2 = new Foo<string>("String Foo", str);
var bar = new Bar<double>(half);

var fooService = new FooService(); // requires 1 type argument
var barService = new BarService(); // requires 1 type argument

fooService.Do(foo1, 13.4);
fooService.Do(foo2, "123456");
barService.Do(bar, 1.1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move services as methods inside entities:

```
abstract class Base<TValue>
{
    protected Converter<TValue> Converter;
    public Base(Converter<TValue> converter) { Converter = converter; }
    public byte[] Convert(TValue value) { return Converter.ConvertFromValue(value); }
    public abstract void DoService(TValue value);
}

class Foo<TValue> : Base<TValue>
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public Foo(string id, Converter<TValue> converter) : base(converter) { Id = id; }
    public override void DoService(TValue value) {/* Foo specific stuff */}
}

class Bar<TValue> : Base<TValue>
{
    public Bar(Converter<TValue> converter) : base(converter) { }
    public override void DoService(TValue value) {/* Bar specific stuff */}
}
```

Then the usage would be like:

```
        DoubleConverter twice = new DoubleConverter(2);
        DoubleConverter half = new DoubleConverter(0.5);
        StringConverter str = new StringConverter(Encoding.ASCII);

        Foo<double> foo1 = new Foo<double>("Twice Foo", twice);
        Foo<string> foo2 = new Foo<string>("String Foo", str);
        Bar<double> bar = new Bar<double>(half);

        foo1.DoService(13.4);
        foo2.DoService("123456");
        bar.DoService(1.1);
```